# powershell выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе

Tags: powershell

если выполнять из C:\Windows\system32 то все хорошо, если с D:\SCRIPTS\sc.ps1 то все не хочет, как это можно исправить?

```
Невозможно загрузить файл D:\SCRIPTS\sc.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

вот кодик

```
$ipv4 = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
    $num = $ipv4.split(".")[-1]
    $ie = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://****/indata.php?nt=$num" -Method POST -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Переходил по указанному адресу? [about_Execution_Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/powershell-scripting/hh847748(v=wps.640))

Comment: А вы пытались переходить по указанной в сообщении об ошибке ссылке?

Comment: Да там сказано через Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted но это ничем хорошим не закончится

Comment: Там кроме Unrestricted еще 5 политик есть

Comment: там только либо разрешить всем сценариям работать либо нет, можно как то работать с одним сценарием?

Comment: можно разрешить на текущий сеанс только.

Comment: а что имеется ввиду под сеансом?

Comment: _- PROCESS
Политика выполнения действует только на текущий сеанс (текущий процесс Windows PowerShell).

Политика выполнения хранится в переменной среды $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference, а не в реестре, и удаляется при завершении сеанса. Изменить политику, изменив значение переменной, невозможно._

Comment: Добавил Set-ExecutionPolicy UNRESTRICTED -Scope PROCESS  но ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88619/discussion-between-grundy-and-keeplod).

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

- Открываем терминал от админа.
- Пишем и запускаем: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- На вопрос отвечаем: A (Да для всех)

Comment: Это единственный во всем интернете, включая англоязычный, простой и верный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Единственное что тут можно добавить - это рекомендацию: если это нужно для разовой установки чего-то - то лучше потом вернуть состояние в стандартное: Set-ExecutionPolicy Default. Это поможет избежать вредоносного ПО :)

Answer (score 11):

По [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/powershell-scripting/hh847748(v=wps.640)), которая указанна у сообщении об ошибке, идет описание политик выполнения.

Для запуска локальных скриптов, нужно установить минимум политику *REMOTESIGNED*, в этом случае можно будет запускать локальные не подписанные скрипты.

Для установки политики можно воспользоваться командой

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy <PolicyName>
```

---

Так же можно ограничить область применения данной политики, для этого можно воспользоваться параметром `-Scope`. По умолчанию политика устанавливается для всех пользователей на локальном компьютере, однако с помощью значения `CurrentUser`, можно ограничить применение только для текущего пользователя, а с помощью значения `Process` применение ограничится текущим запущенным процессом PowerShell.

Таким образом для выполнения можно выполнить сначала команду:

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

и затем запустить нужный скрипт.

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо Serg The Bright

> Пишем и запускаем: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Иногда для локального пользователя запрещено вносить изменения (например, в корп домене).
Мне помогло добавления ключа -Scope CurrentUser (выше было упоминание от Grundy).
Полная команда

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае решением проблемы стал следующий алгоритм:

1. D:\SCRIPTS\sc.ps1 - переходим в папку с скриптом и нажимаем правой мышкой кнопки
2. Выбираем выполнить с помощью PowerShell - появится консоль
3. Я выбрал наивысший уровень запуска