# Терминал не узнает команду

Tags: powershell

Пищу от имени Администратора в терминале

```
C:\Windows\system32>Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned


"Set-ExecutionPolicy" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или 
пакетным файлом.
```

Дело в том что, я хочу запустить виртуальную среду, а для этого нужно запустить скрипт, но система скрипта блокирует

```
Невозможно загрузить файл D:\...\python\1_PyCharm\django\djsite\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1, так 
как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведе...
```

что мне сделать, как разрешение получить?

Comment: Похоже на команду power shell

Comment: да, связана с  power shell. Что теперь делать?

Comment: Выполнять эту команду через power shell, а не cmd. А насчет проблемы выполнения сценариев: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/935212/201445

Comment: нужно установить пакет power shell?

Comment: если виндовс 7 и выше, то уже стоит https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell Просто открыть из меню Старт

Comment: Спасибо, ребята! Все получилось! Но теперь как открыть для конкретного скрипта доступ... я сейчас открыл для всех скриптов, это опасно же получается?

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть на твой первый код то ты пытаешься выполнить `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` в командной строке (CMD) ,но ты должен выполнять эту команду в PowerShell c правами администратора.
Для этого тебе необходимо запустить командную строку от имени Администратора и в ней ввести powershell  и нажать Enter
Если у тебя появится строка приглашения

```
Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.
```

То именно там тебе и нужно выполнять `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Далее у тебя спросят подтверждение действий

после этой процедуры ты уже можешь в этом же окне (Powershell)
можешь запускать свой скрипт

```
D:\...\python\1_PyCharm\django\djsite\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Только если в относительном пути у тебя есть пробелы возьми их в двойные кавычки

```
"D:\...\python\1_PyCharm\django\djsite\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1"
```