# Python. Не запускается файл в виртуальной среде

Tags: python, virtualenv, venv

Всем привет, сейчас решил покопаться в виртуальных средах, и возникла сложность при запуске программы. Такое чувство, что как будто в виртуальной среде venv нет библиотеки g4f, но она точно есть, проверял командой -pip list. Возможно сложность с интерпретатором? у меня, честно говоря, уже каша в голове, буду очень благодарен, если объясните мне, недалекому(использую pipenv)
Ошибка выдается такая:
PS D:\work_table\project> & d:/work_table/project/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
& : Невозможно загрузить файл D:\work_table\project.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу https:/
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
строка:1 знак:3

- & d:/work_table/project/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

PS D:\work_table\project> & d:/work_table/project/.venv/Scripts/python.exe d:/work_table/project/chatGPT.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\work_table\project\chatGPT.py", line 1, in 
import g4f
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from .models    import Model, ModelUtils, *all_models
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\models.py", line 4, in 
from .Provider   import BaseProvider, RetryProvider
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider_*init**.py", line 5, in 
from .deprecated     import *
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider\deprecated_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from .Aibn          import Aibn
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\Provider\deprecated\Aibn.py", line 7, in 
from ...requests import StreamSession
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\requests.py", line 9, in 
from .webdriver import WebDriver, WebDriverSession
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\webdriver.py", line 6, in 
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver_*init*_.py", line 44, in 
from .patcher import IS_POSIX
File "D:\work_table\project.venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 4, in 
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Comment: А вы уверены, что d:/work_table/project/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1 там есть? Что-то меня ps1 смущает.

Comment: Я бы обратил внимание на "выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе".

Comment: @void да меня тоже смущает, но если я прописываю pip list, то высвечиваются пакеты, которые есть на виртуалке, но нет на основной.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я немного не пойму, что это значит. Интерпретатор не видит? Но в VS снизу справа есть плашка, что интерпретатор есть и доступен(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935212/powershell-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5